# Jenkins agent job fails after successful job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I have 2 Jenkins servers because my 2 builds have some incompatible system requirements.

I setup a new node for one of the servers and migrated the jobs from the other server and set them up to run on the node.

The node runs the job just fine and even archives the artifacts (they are linked from the job) but the job throws and exception and gets marked as a failure.

** Below is the output from the jobs **

```
Completed build, now archiving  <-- I print this out at the end of my last build step

FATAL: Remote call on ops-1-jenkins-android-10-186.fam.io failed
java.io.IOException: Remote call on ops-1-jenkins-android-10-186.fam.io failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:748)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher.kill(Launcher.java:940)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:556)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1745)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree.getKillers(ProcessTree.java:151)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$OSProcess.killByKiller(ProcessTree.java:212)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.kill(ProcessTree.java:557)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$UnixProcess.killRecursively(ProcessTree.java:564)
    at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Unix.killAll(ProcessTree.java:488)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:952)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher$KillTask.call(Launcher.java:943)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:63)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Comment: Those stacktraces tell a lot, and nothing at the same time :-) I had all sorts of problem linking a master linux with a slave windows. Are you running latest jenkins/plugins versions? I was facing real bugs, only fixed on latest releases. There were nothing to do unless update.

Comment: I upgraded jenkins & all my plugins and the problem went away.

Comment: If you can then promote this to the correct answer, I would appreciate.

Comment: I voted on it. I'm not sure you can make a comment an "answer"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks [Lovato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3455378/lovato)!

After I updated all the plugins and jenkins things worked just fine.

Comment: You never mentioned which version of jenkins were you using and to which one did you updated to.

Answer (score 1):

We got this error: FATAL: java.io.IOException: Remote call on pm_jenprodslave_1 failed. We found the slave server was unresponsive and had to reboot it. Once it came back the build works again.